# Use Facebook iOS SDK login for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is it possible to use the login from the Facebook iOS SDK to use an active session in a UIWebView?

The regular Facebook web login stores different cookies than the FB SSO via their sdk it seems.

So, what can I do to make a UIWebView like button work from within my app?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

get the Access token for the user & pass it

http://www.facebook.com/PAGE_URL#access_token=xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: no, it's not working and shouldn't. it'll be a security flaw if it did.